# My keras backend tensorflow does not use the gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I install the tensorflow gpu first

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu. 
pip install keras
```

but when I;m running the gpu task. it does not run with the gpu.

 It run with CPU.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
print(keras.__version__)
print(tf.__version__)
2.3.1
2.1.0
```

Comment: try to use pycharm so you can get specified versions of TF and keras and try to run 2.0 instead of 2.1 it will sove ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to user **Tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0** and **Keras=2.3.1** this will solve your problem.